# Google Geo Coding API with RestKit 0.20

Tags: objective-c, json, google-maps, ios6, restkit

I can't figure out to parse this response on an elegant way. I'm trying to match the different field types to an object that contains following attributes.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *postalcode;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *district;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *country;
```

In the past I went through the Dictionary the subfield matched my searched field.

```
 {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "10",
               "short_name" : "10",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Warschauer Straße",
               "short_name" : "Warschauer Straße",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Friedrichshain",
               "short_name" : "Friedrichshain",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg",
               "short_name" : "Friedrichshain-Kreuzberg",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Berlin",
               "short_name" : "Berlin",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Germany",
               "short_name" : "DE",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "10243",
               "short_name" : "10243",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Warschauer Straße 10, 10243 Berlin, Germany",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.51329350,
               "lng" : 13.45246930
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.51464248029150,
                  "lng" : 13.45381828029150
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.51194451970850,
                  "lng" : 13.45112031970850
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: There is no "elegant" way. Just hard-code the full getters, mapping them to the JSON as you see it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've came up with following solution. I've defined an Dictionary and overwrote the Setter to parse the incoming dictionary into my own parser:

```
-(void)addressByGoogle: (NSDictionary*)newAddressComponents{

    for (NSArray *googleResult in newAddressComponents) {

        for (NSArray *fields in googleResult) {

            if ([[fields valueForKey:@"types"] count] >= 1) {

                NSString *googleType = [[fields valueForKey:@"types"] objectAtIndex:0];

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"sublocality"]) {
                    self.district = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"country"]) {
                    self.country = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"locality"]) {
                    self.city = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"street_number"]) {
                    self.streetnumber = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"route"]) {
                    self.address = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }

                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"postal_code"]) {
                    self.postalcode = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }
                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"administrative_area_level_1"]) {
                    self.adminAreaLevel1 = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }
                if ( [googleType isEqualToString:@"administrative_area_level_2"]) {
                    self.adminAreaLevel2 = [fields valueForKey:@"long_name"];
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

- (void) setAddressComponents:(NSDictionary *)newAddressComponents{
    [self addressByGoogle: newAddressComponents];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696042/jim) said, there is no elegant way to map this object using Restkit, what you could do instead is to map this format directly into an "ugly object" and wrap that object with another that has the interface as you want.

Something like:

```
@interface MYMappedAddress : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *addressComponents;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *types;
@property (nonatomic) MYGeometry *geometry;
@property (nonatomic) NSString * formattedAddress;

@end

@interface MYAddress : MYMappedAddress

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *postalcode;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *district;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *country;

@end
```